# Check if cell is contained in group of cells to add its value to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets document that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
1
2   X   X   3
3   Z   Y   2
4   W   Z   6
5
```

How can I do so that if the element in column A is one of the elements of column B, its corresponding value in column C is added to column D? In this case, column D must have this values:

```
D2 = 3, because X is in column B
D3 = 2, because Z is in column B
D4 = 0, because W is not in column B
```

Many thanks in advane!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 FILTER(B2:C, COUNTIF(B2:B, A2:A)), 2, 0))*1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A)*C2:C),,)
```

[image]